# What is the correct way to get xticks and yticks values with Cartopy and Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

Good evening, all !

Today I tried to put in place a system to plot automatically gridded data using python (3.5), matplotlib (2.2.3) and Cartopy (0.16), all under Windows 10. I would like to get xticks and yticks values (coordinates shown in a figure) and show them to the user (it is possible for him to set his own values). The problem is that the methods 'get_xticks()' and 'get_yticks()' seem to give weird results.

Here is an example code:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy

lon = numpy.arange(-180,180,1)
lat = numpy.arange(-90,90,1)
data = numpy.ones((len(lat), len(lon)))

ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
ax.pcolormesh(lon, lat, data, transform=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(), cmap='jet')
ax.set_extent((-180,180,-90,90), cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()

shp_file = cartopy.io.shapereader.natural_earth(resolution='110m', category='physical', name='land')
for land in cartopy.io.shapereader.Reader(shp_file).records():
    ax.add_geometries(land.geometry, cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='#e6e6e6')

gl = ax.gridlines(crs=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                  linewidth=1, color='black', alpha=1, linestyle='-')
gl.xlabels_top = True
gl.ylabels_left = True
gl.xlines = True
gl.ylines = True

plt.show()

print(gl.axes.get_xticks())
print(gl.axes.get_yticks())
```

Results of the previous are:

```
[-200. -150. -100.  -50.    0.   50.  100.  150.  200.] for X axis
[-100.  -75.  -50.  -25.    0.   25.   50.   75.  100.] for Y axis
```

I can't understand where Cartopy and Matplotlib are taking those values ... and as I just started to use Cartopy, I can't imagine its a bug ... I am used to work with Matplotlib to plot different kind of timeseries. But here, I am struggling seriously to understand what's going on and to find a solution.

So my question is simple, is there a simple way to get the xticks and yticks values as shown in the figure ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Olivier

Update: I just add the figure we can obtain with the code I posted above.
[image: cartopy example]

Comment: Why do you find the values printed strange? They match nicely with your input range of `lon = numpy.arange(-180,180,1)` and `lat = numpy.arange(-90,90,1)`

Comment: I was expecting to see [-180, -120, -60, 0, 60, 120, 180] for Longitudes as displayed in the figure with the function 'get_xticks()', and not [-200, -150, -100, -50, 0, 50, 100, 150, 200]. Or there is something that I don't understand here ?

Comment: I can’t see any figure here. Plz update

Comment: I forgot that one ... Done !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I think the clue is in the `matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator` object that gridliner defaults to using:

```
print(gl.xlocator.tick_values(*ax.get_xlim()))
print(gl.ylocator.tick_values(*ax.get_ylim()))
```

gives

```
[-180. -120.  -60.    0.   60.  120.  180.]
[-100.  -80.  -60.  -40.  -20.    0.   20.   40.   60.   80.  100.]
```

Comment: My answer is a bit late, and I am very sorry for that. The two lines of code you have posted are working great and I will use them for now. Certainly a nice one ! I totally lost hope on that. Thanks again !